# Prevent form resubmission and insert into database on page refresh

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a servlet which takes data from the form and inserts it in the database.In servlet I make use of beans and get/set data via beans.Once the insert happens ,user is redirected to the view which shows as how exactly the page looks.This page is JSP. Now when I do this page refresh(jsp),it again does form data insert into the database.Now I need to prevent this from happening.What I was thinking was rather than redirecting it to jsp,let me redirect to another servlet and from that servlet let me do the get request and forward it to jsp for view.With this approach, I have refactor  my jsp and I have lot many jsp which will be impacted.

Is their any other way I can prevent insert into the database when page refresh is done ?

I also checked on database side assuming that I can add unique constraints, I do have some unique columns that gets generated via initial servlet,so on each insert values are different,so I cannot really use the solution on DB side.

Can someone suggest me if there exists work arounds for this ?

Update:Adding code which does insert, I am refreshing the page manually.Seems like this is bug which I missed out to consider earlier.It does the insert correctly in the database and shows correctly all data in the view jsp.When the view jsp is refreshed, I get double inserts in the database.

Update .removed the code.Will post relevant parts of the code rather than whole code.

Issue is resolved.

```
 javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = request.getSession();            
        if (session.getAttribute("insertflag") == null) {
            mybean sf = new mybean();
            sf.insert(form);
            session.setAttribute("insertflag", insertid);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test/showtestform.jsp");                
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } else {                
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/errorpage.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
```

In error page jsp I remove the attribute set and then provide the link in that page to come back again to home page.

Comment: How are you doing your page refresh?

Comment: how are you posting using GET or POST ?

Comment: Ramesh its post request.With Multipart request, I think only post works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple workaround can be that you put a flag in Session; whenever insert is done.. And before inserting always check session if this flag is present.

In the servlet; 
Before inserting into the database; make following check:

```
if (session.getAttribute("recordInsertedSuccessfully") == null )
{
   //proceed with insertion
   //after inserting into the database we should do :
   session.putAttribute("recordInsertedSuccessfully","true");
} else {
   //case of form re-submission
}
```

If there is a possibility of a valid scenario of user inserting two of these records ( might be user browsing and then again inserting record in same table ; which is a valid scenario ) ; then we need to also add following code before the form is shown to user:

```
session.removeAttribute("recordInsertedSuccessfully");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this Deepak ?

Comment: details added. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah its a good solution, but Deepak is there any other more stable solution for it ?

Comment: Deepak, When should the flag be removed?

Answer (score 1):

submit your form using javascript with onclick event

do not submit form using  `<input type=submit>` and use  `<input type=button>`

Comment: I think changing the input type from submit to button will break my client side validation logic.I dont feel that issue lies with button.This is form where user adds the data and this data is processed by the servlet and after processing it forwards he requets to JSP via dispatcher to show it to user.Its this jsp which when refreshed do double inserts.I just need to prevent this from happening.However I will try this approach for some other functionality which I am doing since this approach is also good one.Thanks Manish.I dont know if this is browser specific issue.I get this in IE.

Answer (score 0):

What you say about session attributes?
on form Submit create new session attribute and invalidate it when successfully work done.

And on action servlet, add condition if session attribute is available then continue the form submission if not then redirect to form page.